# Cannot set Django to work with smtp.gmail.com

Tags: python, django, smtp

I've been trying to get django to work with gmail's smtp server to send mails but I always get this traceback. Any help will be most appreciated.

## ----- settings.py -----

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-password'

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

## ---- python shell -----

> > from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
> >
> > email = EmailMessage('Mail Test', 'This is a test', to=['somemail@something.com'])
> >
> > email.send()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/fiodorovich/Envs/fdict/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 251, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/home/fiodorovich/Envs/fdict/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 86, in send_messages
sent = self._send(message)
File "/home/fiodorovich/Envs/fdict/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 104, in _send
email_message.message().as_string())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 701, in sendmail
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
SMTPSenderRefused: (530, '5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. z15sm10449686anl.15', 'webmaster@localhost')
```

Edit: New errors when made the modification suggested by unni. The shell won't execute and I'm getting this error message

```
**EMAIL_HOST_USER  = 'some.account@gmail.com'**
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Is that a direct C+P of the settings?

Comment: well those aren't really the account name and password, but the rest is a C+p

Comment: Do they show up when you start the Django REPL?

Comment: I am not sure how to test that, trying to figure out right now

Comment: Start the shell, import `django.conf.settings`, and see if it exists.

Comment: `ImportError: No module named settings`

Comment: Strange, those settings work for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have recently set this up and had a slightly different settings.py config.

Move:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

to the top above EMAIL_HOST

Add:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'user@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'user@gmail.com'
```

Comment: it doesn't matter where `EMAIL_USE_TLS` is in relation to the other settings. All that stuff is executed in one swell foop

Comment: @Sheena But this answer got 6 upvotes yet. Means there is something in it

Answer (score 17):

Change your settings like this :

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-password'

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Then try:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
>>> email = EmailMessage('Mail Test', 'This is a test', to=['somemail@something.com'])
>>> email.send()
```

This should return with the status 1, which means it worked.

Comment: I just added the error message this produces to my original question

Comment: @la_f0ka I just wanted to emphasize that line don't use ** in the settings file. I have edited the code above. Please try it again.

Comment: This is the correct answer!  The current accepted answer (to change order of `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True`) is incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and I searched for half a day to find a solution. Most of the proposed solutions are talking about where you should initialize EMAIL_USE_TLS in relation to the other settings. I don't think this is a solution for the problem.

I found the solution at: 
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en
and finally
https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

If you are testing your project on a local machine, you should go to the latter link, and enable "Access for less secure apps".

Comment: This should be the approved answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youruser'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*********'
DEFAULT_EMAIL_FROM = 'youremail@gmail.com'
```

works fine

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to this link 
https://www.google.com/settings/u/2/security/lesssecureapps?pageId=none
and turn on the access for less secure apps

this option allows django to access your email and send email via it .