# How do I send_mail in Django with a custom from email address?

Tags: django, gmail, sendmail

I'm trying to use the send_mail feature of Django. I am building a contact form where user's put in their email address. I want to send off an email with "from" as the address the user inputs. I tried using a gmail account in my settings.py but this just replaces the from address. I then tried using a webfaction smtp account, but, if I try to send this email to a gmail, google apps, or googlegroups account I get:

`Sender address rejected: Please use Gmail's SMTP servers`

It's important to set the from address because I have all these going to a Google Group so users can respond to them like a collective ticket inbox. I can set the reply-to header but it's still not perfect. The weird thing is that if I use send_mail in the Django shell it sends it off just fine with the custom from address, but that doesn't seem to be using my settings.py smtp settings?

Comment: Do you get this error message for all messages, or just anything that claims to be from someone@gmail.com?

Comment: I believe it is just from a gmail address. Their support indicated that it has to be from an address registered in their system. I guess that means I need to find another SMTP server that will support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to send to gmail users as if from a gmail account, use the settings at [Cannot set Django to work with smtp.gmail.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877452/cannot-set-django-to-work-with-smtp-gmail-com)

Comment: Thanks, but the from address is supplied by the user's input on the contact form, so it changes. From my research this is an intentional restriction by google to prevent scam being sent from their servers. I can set a reply-to address, which is better than nothing.